# Dumping a full expansion of a complex data structure

Tags: javascript, node.js, console.log

In node.js, `console.log` on being given an object or array instead of a string, will dump an expanded representation of same, which is good. However it only goes down a couple of levels before it stops and just starts printing things as `[Object]`.

I'm looking for a full expanded representation that goes all the way down to basic values like strings and numbers. Is there a way to get that in node.js, using `console.log` or otherwise, without having to write my own pretty-print function from scratch?

Comment: I've never used it, but you could try `console.dir`

Comment: @Fallexe ah yes, the linked question has the answer, thanks!